# Symbolic footnote in longtable with p type

Tags: longtable

I am using the longtable package to make a nice little table.
One entry of the table shall have a symbolic footnote, for which I use:

```
%Symbolic footnote command
\newcounter{savefootnote}
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
   \setcounter{savefootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{symfootnote}}%
   \ifnum\value{footnote}>8\setcounter{footnote}{0}\fi%
   \let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
   \footnote{#1}%
   \let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
   \setcounter{symfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefootnote}}%
}
```

While everything works with the c-type commands, it does not when using p-. Then the footnote has index 1.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

%Symbolic footnote command
\newcounter{savefootnote}
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
   \setcounter{savefootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{symfootnote}}%
   \ifnum\value{footnote}>8\setcounter{footnote}{0}\fi%
   \let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
   \footnote{#1}%
   \let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
   \setcounter{symfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefootnote}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.59\textwidth}}
Test & Test\symfootnote{With Symbol!}\\
\caption{Test table}
\label{tab:pertModels}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Footnotes have no place in tables. Use tables notes instead, in this case `threeparttablex` will be useful. In this case it is a bit of a miracle that `\foonote` actually escapes.

Comment: No offense, but it is my personal opinion that stack exchange is a place to learn and help. Questioning the intent of the question does not add too much here. I also try to avoid this, but there are circumstances in which this makes sense. Hence longtable has explicitly incorporated compatibility with this (which is why I am using it here instead of the standard table/tabular approach)

Comment: Sure but a lot of people on the site start with the wrong assumptions, and try to solve every problem by hitting it with a hammer. Your question does not explain anything as to why this solution is chosen. And I still think bottom of the page footnotes should not be used in relation to tables.

Comment: Agreed :) But I tend to think that there are always reasons for exceptions. So a command like yours would be a perfect start for an anwer followed by a big "BUT ... if you really need it, here is the way to go"

Comment: Also, longtable deliberately supports \footnote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is somewhat simpler and allows you to use any symbol (optional argument). The downside is that you have to manually restore normal footnotes.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\symfootnote}[2][*]{% #1 = symbol (optional), #2 = text
  \xdef\thempfn{#1}%
  \if\thempfn\thefootnote
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \xdef\thempfn{\thefootnote}%
  \fi
  \footnote{#2}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.59\textwidth}}
Test & Test\symfootnote{With Symbol!}\\
Test & Test\symfootnote[$\dagger$]{second footnote}\\
Test & Test\symfootnote[\thefootnote]{how to include normal footnotes}\\
\caption{Test table}
\label{tab:pertModels}
\end{longtable}
\def\thempfn{\thefootnote}% restore normal footnotes

%\thefootnote
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great!!! Before I accept the answer I do have two questions: 1) how exactly does it work without using `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%` ? 2) I just noticed the edit. What was the issue with the prior solution? Cause the prior one did not have the final restore command in it (which makes it cleaner)

Comment: To answer that I first need to check out the difference between both ;) What is the reason that the restore command cannot be part of the command definition? Is it linked to def/xdef?

Comment: I tend to tweak answers after I submit them.  I find that if I don't send them immediately, I won't send them al all, but then I think of ways to improve them.  The big problem was that \footnotetext was ignoring changes unless I used \xdef, The \footnote source (see CTAN source2e) uses `\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}`, but even that wasn't enough.  I know that \insert is a bit indeterminant regarding when it expands things.

Comment: So this is a super cool and hacky solution :) Thanks a lot! The only thing that might be a bit "dangerous" is that the restore command needs to be placed manually, which may be forgotten and then suddenly all remaining footnotes are symbols

Comment: I tried creating an environment which would automatically restore footnotes, but couldn't pull it off.