# How to use a symbol as footnote marker with hyperref and cleveref packages

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, footnotes, cleveref

I need to refer multiple times in the text to the same footnote with `hyperref` support. This can be achieved using the `cleveref` package, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10116/153361). My problem is that I would also like to use symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers. I tried to follow the suggestions given in the first two answers to this [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/826/153361), but the code did not compile.

Here is a minimal working example. I would like to use an asterisk in place of the number 1. Can anybody help me, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

\begin{document}    
Here I have a footnote\footnote{\label{first}Footnote text.}.

Here I have the same footnote\cref{first}.  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551566/symbolic-footnote-in-longtable-with-p-type

Answer (score 1):

footnotemark expects a number in the optional argument. You could use simply \textsuperscript:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\textsuperscript{\normalfont #1}#3}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
Here I have a footnote\footnote{\label{first}Footnote text.}.

Here I have the same footnote\cref{first}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reference boxes seem to have different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with `footmisc`, no need for `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
Here I have a footnote\footnote{\label{first}Footnote text.}.

Here I have the same footnote\footref{first}.  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would like the size of the reference boxes to be consistent.

Comment: The size of boxes is calculated by `hyperref`, instead of messing with that, I'd rather disable them alltogether (e.g. with `hidelinks`).