# How to use an asterisk as footnote mark, once

Tags: formatting, header-footer, footnotes, texlive

I'm writing my PhD thesis. The university requires that chapters that use copyright protected work must have a footnote marked in their title declaring the copyright protected materials. The title footnote must be an asterisk and all other footnotes need to use the arabic style starting with 1.

The usual suggestions say to include `\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}` and then I can switch between symbol style and arabic style with `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` and `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}`. But something about putting my included tex files in higher directory is interfering with the correct result. Arabic, Roman, and alph styles work so long as the the footmisc package is not included. When included the follow error is called on the footnote.

```
(hyperref)                removing `\uppercase' on input line 5.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \baselinestretch 
                            
l.5 ..., Phys. Rev. D\textbf{76}, 094513 (2007).}}
```

The following is the main tex file that assembles the sub-files into one document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{slashed}             %provides /slash for Feynman slash notation
\usepackage{tamuconfig}          %Something from the university, mostly don't question it
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         %Font style, default from univesity
\usepackage{graphicx}            %Import graphics
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png} %Default graphic extension is *.png
\graphicspath{ {./graphic/} }    %Graphics located om ./graphic
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %Include hyperlinks in PDF, but don't highlight them
\usepackage{amssymb}             %Math symbols
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}   %Suggested method to allow asterisks for footnote marker

\begin{document}
\include{data/titlepage} % This is simply a file that formats and adds your titlepage, please do not edit this unless you have a specific need.
\include{data/abstract}
\include{data/dedication}
\include{data/acknowledgements}
\include{data/contributors}
\include{data/nomenclature}

\include{data/lists}  % This is simply a file that formats and adds your toc, lof, and lot, please do not edit this unless you have a specific need.

\include{data/Ch1}
\include{data/Ch2}
\include{data/Ch3}
\include{data/Ch4}
\include{data/Ch5}
\include{data/Ch6}

%fix spacing in bibliography, if any...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\oldbibitem}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{{\normalsize\rm REFERENCES}}

%This file is a .bib database that contains the sources.
%This removes the dependency on the previous file
%bibliography.tex.
\bibliography{data/myReference}
\include{data/appendices}
\end{document}
```

If you need tamuconfig.sty to figure out if the university broke something, it is at https://github.com/bardsoftware/template-thes-tamu/blob/master/tamuconfig.sty.

Then I should be able to use the following to insert the copyright notice as a footnote on the title:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} %Switch to symbol marker footnotes
\chapter[\uppercase{Title}]{\uppercase{Title}\footnote{copyright notice}} %Chapter title
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} %Switch back to arabic footnote marker
```

I get the above error when I do.

It is possible because it was done on pages 1 and 14 of https://oaktrust.library.tamu.edu/bitstream/handle/1969.1/173421/LIU-DISSERTATION-2018.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y and the university requires it.

In the event that it matters, I'm compiling the document with TeX Live; `pdflatex --version` produces `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` among other things.

Comment: This is likely not the issue but sometimes it is, but could you try loading `hyperref` last and seeing if the issue persists? When `hyperref` is not loaded last (or close to last, check the docs for what needs loading after), strange errors can occur

Comment: The error was not resolved by moving hyperref to the last included package.

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me why you need to load `footmisc`. The lines you quoted to make the footnote using symbols works perfectly fine without using `footmisc`.

Comment: Here's 3 instances of solutions with the ```footmisc``` package. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561715/how-to-use-a-symbol-as-footnote-marker-with-hyperref-and-cleveref-packages https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574134/choose-footnote-symbol-double-asterisk https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers
And I get this error without it which is much worse than undefined control sequence:
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
          \T1/cmr/m/n/10 
l.6 ..., Phys. Rev. D\textbf{76}, 094513 (2007).}}

Comment: "If you need tamuconfig.sty" you should be able to test that (and remove from the example if not needed).  Please edit your example so it is an example of the problem and generates the error shown.

Comment: I do need tamuconfig.sty because it contains the control sequences that define the title page. I don't know if you need it to figure out if they broke something that makes ```\baselinestretch```  an undefined control sequence instead of correct as Willie Wong expects. But I can make an unfancy version to see if they did in fact break something.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I flattened the directory structure so that all files are in the same place as the main tex file and as Willie Wong expected, ```footmisc``` was not needed and almost everything works correctly. The arabic footnotes don't start at 1.