# Choose footnote symbol (double asterisk)

Tags: footnotes

Here is my current Tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text\protect\footnote[1]{Footnote 1}\\
\noindent Some other text\protect\footnote[1]{Footnote 2}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I would like the footnotes to be respectively * and **.

Comment: If you use `\footnote[1]` twice, why do you expect them to produce different results?

Comment: I don't expect my code to produce different results. It was just to illustrate, where the footnotes should be. replacing the number results in other symbols. I tried different approaches but wasn't able to make the **

Comment: Right. Just saying `\footnote[1]` will normally produce an asterisk. If you want `**` it's usually `\footnote[7]`. Probably best to use the wiley symbol set as shown in the answer below, in this case.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551566/symbolic-footnote-in-longtable-with-p-type/551593?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.5791#551593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard setup the double star comes at 7th place, so you could type your second footnote as `\footnote[7]{...}`. Better use the `wiley` numbering provided by `footmisc`

[image]

such that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\setfnsymbol{wiley}

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Footnote 1}

Some other text\footnote{Footnote 2}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works like I would like it to. I wasn't aware og the existence of "\setfnsymbol{wiley}"