# Author's affiliations with * symbols

Tags: author, affiliation

I am new to Latex and I want following style of author's affliation
[image]

I am getting different symbols but not the required series of *

```
\author{Max Mustermann\thanks{Prof. Dr. Max Mustermann, 
University of Hohenheim, Chair of Banking, Street 123, 01234 Stuttgart, E-Mail: max.mustermann@uni-hohenheim.de}{ } \and 
Michaela Mustermann
\thanks{Prof. Dr. Michaela Mustermann,
 University of Hohenheim, Chair of Banking, 
Street 123, 01234 Stuttgart,
 E-Mail: Michaela.mustermann@uni-hohenheim.de}}
```

I am getting this output
[image]

Please help

Comment: We'd need a minimal example of what you did so far.

Comment: Since this is related to author affiliations, it might not be an explicit duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers , but there you might find a workaround for what you need.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Choose footnote symbol (double asterisk) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574134/choose-footnote-symbol-double-asterisk) but then no minimal example I can't tell.

Comment: Please have a look at my code and my output. Thanks in advance