# LyX: How to change the footnote symbols

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX 2.3. Whenever I am adding a footnote following `insert>Footnote`, by default the footnote sybmol is appeared as a number. For some particular footnotes, I need to change the footnote symbols to asterisk in place of numbers. Would anyone please suggest how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551566/symbolic-footnote-in-longtable-with-p-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the symbols ∗† ‡ § ... for footnotes, just add `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` to the `Latex Preamble` in in Document → Settings.

Then, the code preview pane should show some similar to this example:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really want to learn LaTeX. ;)
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
foo\footnote{foo } foo\footnote{foo} foo\footnote{foo} foo\footnote{foo}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

To return to the numeric footnote temporally, for instance for the
second footnote only, without counting the first, you can limit the redefinition to a single footnote (or a text with several footnotes) in this way:

```
{\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}
\footnote{foo}}
```

Of course, if there are many numeric footnotes and a few footnotes with symbols, just set locally the `\fnsymbol` format and count in this way, without touching at all the preamble.

Comment: Would you please suggest how to go back to default footnote symbol (number) in the same document? Only for particular footnotes, I have to use asterisks but in other case have to use number. Thanks

Comment: @1118716 Place the redefinition of  `\thefootnote` within a group `{...}` or some environment in the main text  (`\begin{...) ...\end{...}`) to limit the scope to a chunk of text ,or redefine it again when needed  to return to the `\arabic{footnote}` format. Of course, you cannot include  LaTeX commands  directly in main text, but using ERT (Evil Red Text) boxes (Ctrl+L).

Comment: @1118716 If  footnotes with symbols should not be counted, you must also change the counter accordingly, e.g., with `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}`. In  [Wikibooks](https://en..org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters)  you have an easy guide to deal with counters.